# What are the tax implications of earnings from the stock market (BSE)?

Tags: taxes, stocks, income-tax, india, capital-gain

I am planning to sell all my stock and have all my money transferred to my own savings bank account. What is my tax liability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have held the stocks longer than a year, then there is no tax apart from the STT that is already deducted when you sell the shares.

If you have held the stock for less than a year, you would have to pay short term capital gains at the rate of 15% on the profit.

Edit:

If you buy different shares from the total amount or profits, it makes no difference to taxes.

Comment: Isn't the rate of tax on short term capital gain 15%, unless that has changed for the AY 2015-16?

Comment: @BijoThomas Thanks. You are right its 15%. Updated the answer. Mixed it with something else :)

Comment: so will i have to pay income tax over it ? suppose my yearly salary is 5,00,00 and i earn 20,000 (out of which 10000 is my profit) in stocks after holding them for 13 months, so my total income is 520000. According to indian tax code anything above 250000 is liable for being taxed so will i have to pay for 5,20,000-2,50,000= 2,70,000.Is my taxable income 2,70,000 and if it not how much is my taxable income then ?

Comment: Your profit is Rs10,000/- and tax if any will be on Rs 10,000. As you have held these stocks for more than 1 year, there is no tax. You would have to pay tax on Rs 5,00,000 as per the slab, i.e. NIL for 2,50,000 and 10% for next.

Comment: What if I reinvested the amount in other shares (intra day trading etc?)

Comment: Income from intraday trading is considered as business income from speculation, not as short/long term capital gain. Further, spending money on intraday is generally considered as Trading and not as Investment.

Comment: In case if you reinvested in other stocks for short term or long term, the determination of short or long will be based on the date you bought a unit of share. For example, bought ABC Co. for 15000, sold after 13 months for 20000, you get long term capital gain of 5000, which is not taxable. Reinvested 20000 by buying XYZ Co., sold after 7 months for 24000, you get short term capital gain of 4000, which is taxable at 15%.